# Place Stack with Dynamic Size Content Inside ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to place a Stack inside a ListView. However, the Stack has a an expandable Card (i.e. dynamic height) so I cannot place the Stack inside ConstrainedBox.

I have tried to place the Stack inside IntrinsicHeight widget but all page content was disappeared.

Here is some of my code:

```
Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                top: 0.0,
                left: 0.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: Image.asset(),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: _width * 5.55 / 100,
                right: _width * 5.55 / 100,
                top: _height * 25.31 / 100,
                child: ClipPath(
                  clipper: BottomCardClipper(
                    screenWidth: _width,
                    screenHeight: _height,
                  ),
                  child: Card(
                    // This card is expandable
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

And I got this error:

```
I/flutter ( 4412): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4412): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 4412): RenderStack object was given an infinite size during layout.
I/flutter ( 4412): This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put
I/flutter ( 4412): inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed the stack inside ConstrainedBox and added a variable height to its minHeight property. I also created a function to calculate the Stack height.
So, when the page is rendered or each time the Card's height changes, I calculate the stack height and set the state of minHeight variable.
The following code explains the solution:

First, I defined the Stack height variable and a GlobalKey to get Card height:

```
double _stackHeight = 0.0;
GlobalKey key = GlobalKey<_BusinessCardState>();
```

Then, I placed the Stack inside ConstrainedBox widget and assigned the key to the Card widget:

```
Scaffold(
    body: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: <Widget>[
        ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: _stackHeight),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                top: 0.0,
                left: 0.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: Image.asset(),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: _width * 5.55 / 100,
                right: _width * 5.55 / 100,
                top: _height * 25.31 / 100,
                child: ClipPath(
                  clipper: BottomCardClipper(
                    screenWidth: _width,
                    screenHeight: _height,
                  ),
                  child: Card(
                    key: key,
                    ...
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
  );
```

After that, I created a function to calculate Card height using its key:

```
_getCardHeight() {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final RenderBox renderBoxRed = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    return renderBoxRed.size.height;
  }
```

And finally, I called that function when the page finish rendering inside initState function:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (SchedulerBinding.instance.schedulerPhase ==
        SchedulerPhase.persistentCallbacks) {
      SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((context) {
        setState(() {
          _stackHeight = _getCardHeight();
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

The _getCardHeight() function can be called any time I need to set the state of _stackHeight variable.